# OS X alternative to Filemaker

Tags: macos, database, productivity, filemaker

We're a small office (20 people) on OS X that needs to replace our old Appleworks databases with something that's a little more future-proof. We have the problem where something like Filemaker is a bit too expensive and bit too overkill for what we need. However, it's very suited for an office environment, since databases are easily shared over the network.

We're aware of Bento, Filemaker's little cousin, but worried it's not really appropriate, since it limits network sharing to only 5 users.

Is anyone aware of a similar product for OS X that's reliable, and might provide the middle ground we're looking for?

Comment: I don't use this, so I'm not comfortable answering, but perhaps use a MySQL or PostgreSQL server with Navicat as a front-end? http://www.navicat.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at 4th dimension software. (www.4D.com)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using AppleWorks you *could* find [LiveCode](http://runrev.com) useful, it evolves from HyperCard (actually it is inspired by it) so you could find some old Claris footprint.

It's very multiplatform (Mac/Win/Lin/iOS/Android) and reasonably priced. I'm not sure if developing a database for internal use falls into "commercial" license.
Please note that I didn't develop anything with it that is I don't have first hand experience, but when it seemed interesting that I kept a mental note about it.

A question similar to this one but focusing on open source software has been asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/30776/open-source-alternative-to-filemaker-or-access) on SO, most likely you'll have to check [kexi](http://www.kexi-project.org) and [camelot](http://www.python-camelot.com)

**edit:**

I didn't notice the question was almost two years old.
You've probably solved your needs by now, if so I'm curious about hearing what the solution is as it can come handy